# Android app is not launching with facebook SDK 3.6 getting some android support v4 jar file issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, jar

I have added facebook sdk 3.6 to my project. And when i tried to run my project i got error of multiple android support v4 jar files and i searched in google and i found to remove ant one jar or copy same jar file.

[Jar Mismatch Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045568/jar-mismatch-found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list)

[Facebook SDK for Android duplicate support library on dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517222/facebook-sdk-for-android-duplicate-support-library-on-dependencies)

So first i tried to remove my project android support v4 jar and added facebook Sdk 3.6's jar to my project then error has been removed but the problem i am facing right now is i am not able to launch my app not in device also and not in emulator.

Then again i searched in google and i found this solution

[Jar Mismatch Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045568/jar-mismatch-found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list)

i tried with this and other so many solution but after replacing this jar files, or removing jar files from my project i am not able to launch my app.

I have tried to create new project and copied my all content in new project also but getting same problem not able to launch my application in both real devices and emulator.

All the time when i try to run my app i am getting **Launching app (100%)** but it is not launching. and if i try to do some modification then i get **Eclipse is not responding** and forcefully i have to close eclipse and again i have to start eclipse which is very time consuming.

I am stuck in this issue since morning please help. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I have tried with this solution also [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793722/error-on-add-library-project-in-eclipse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="iqual.fidol_final"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="iqual.fidol_final.FacebookLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShowVideo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Solution**

`I just have restarted my PC and now it's working. Don't know what happened but just this tricks works`

Comment: Do you still get jar mismatch error ?

Comment: post your current log details

Comment: @deniz, i am not getting any error. but i am not able to launch my app in real device as well as emulator.

Comment: @GrIsHu, No now i am not getting missmatch error, but i am not able to run my project.

Comment: try clean your project and build again. hope it will help you

Comment: @deniz, i have tried but no luck. don't know why!!!

Comment: Firstly i would say to add the facebook sdk in your project as library and do not add the support library explicitly in your project just remove it if you have added. And then after adding sdk clean and build your project. In this way do you get any error ? @InnocentKiller

Comment: @GrIsHu, No i did not got any error but still app is not launching.

Comment: Why the app is not launching ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: @GrIsHu, I am not getting any error, just i can see **Launching App: (100%) at bottom bar. and keep running only but not launching.

Comment: Have you added launcher activity in your manifest ? Which is your launcher activity ? @InnocentKiller

Comment: @GrIsHu, Check my manifest file. i have updated it.

Comment: Try out with the different emulator by closing your current emulator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46209/discussion-between-innocentkiller-and-grishu)

Comment: Got solution, i don't know why but i have just restart my PC and now it's working fine. BTW thank you to all.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. This issue occurred because the support V4 library had different versions. To solve this issue copy the v4 library in your facebook sdk and paste it in your project. Don't forget to build path.

Comment: There is nothing in log cat, i have mentioned in my question only that i am not able to launch my app that's it. I am getting **launching app(100%)** But not getting in device and emulator it just keep running and nothing is showing in device or emulator.

Comment: clean u r project and run

Comment: I have tried this more than 30 times but still no luck!!! Now just tired with this and it's frustrating me now.

Comment: if u have more than one dex file for same lib it will also bother u r project

Comment: But facebook SDK is just library project that i have added for reference.

Comment: u have to add it as lib in u r project

Comment: I am not getting what you try to say, can you tell exactly which file i have to add, and from where it is available exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any other library projects added, pls check on it too.

Paste it v4 jar on Facebook lib project . and if have v4 jar on main project,  remove it.

Once complete close all lib files and project then reopen the project.

Comment: No, I dont have any other library project. and i have done this too copied support jar to only library project and then tried to restart eclipse and run my app but getting no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i would say to add the facebook sdk in your project as library and do not add the support library explicitly in your project just remove it if you have added support jar into your build path. And then after adding sdk clean and build your project.

In this way do you get any error ?

Then just right click on your project `Go to >Properties>Android Tools>Add support library..` and then try to clean your project and build again. By selecting both facebook sdk and your project.

This will solve your issue i guess..

Comment: I have tried with your solution, but let me clear one thing to you is that i am not getting any kind of error. Second i have exactly did same what you told but still my app is not launching.

Comment: Have you added launcher activity in your manifest ? Which is your launcher activity ?