# setProgressViewOffset(boolean, int, int) is undefined for the type SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

Using the new SwipeRefreshLayout from Support Revision 21 (or latest today, from sdk manager) I get it to work but I need to move down the view using

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
....
mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
mSwipeLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 100, 150)
```

> The method setProgressViewOffset(boolean, int, int) is undefined for
>   the type SwipeRefreshLayout.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Talklittle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57490/talklittle) was right.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13517304/3064486)  fixed my problem.

I had facebook SDK which had an older support library than the project I was working on.

> t seems like the different projects are using 2 separate support libraries and there for the checksum is different.
>
> You must repeat this for both the Facebook SDK project and the app you are building.
>
> what I do when I get this error is:
>
> **1.** Right click the project.
>
> **2.** Android Tools -> Add support library
>
> **3.** Accept the downloading of the library.

this insures 2 things:

> **A.** You get the newest version of the support library from the Google sources.
>
> **B.** You have the EXACT same library in all your projects.

Comment: I can. In one hour. :)

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and rebuild. You may be compiling the old `SwipeRefreshLayout` into your APK.

If you are using gradle, make sure you are referencing version 21.0.0 of the support-v4 library.

Or if you are using the JAR, make sure you don't have the old JAR version being included.

Comment: You were right. I searched for a way to make sure they we're the same and it helped me. Please confirm my answer above.